# How to quantify moderation effect in an intervention study with multiple time points?

Tags: interaction, psychology, mixed-model, pre-post-comparison

I want to measure a moderation effect between 3 continuous variable in an intervention study. I am using scores from self-report measures of masculinity, emotionality, and psychological distress. The idea is that emotionality will be manipulated via an experimental intervention designed to increase emotionality, and then emotionality will moderate the relationship between masculinity and distress. I hypothesize that as emotionality increases due to the intervention, the relationship between masculinity and distress decreases or is no longer significant. There will be two groups (treatment vs. control) and 3 time points (pre-, post-, and follow-up). I am most interested in measuring this moderation as variables change between time 1 and 2, and time 2 and time 3.

Should I be using a mixed effects model, using treatment as fixed and time as random effect and use change scores on emotionality between time points? Distress would be the outcome variable. I am feeling confused by how to best measure this moderation considering it involves change across time points and deciding on if I should use change scores.

Any help would be much appreciated in terms of conceptualizing this model!

Comment: I think you are on exactly the right track